# Ag-grid enterprise: possibility to deselect cells in rangeselection via user interaction

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am currently using the Ag-grid enterprise angular version 20.2.0 in a project and we cannot find an option to deselect already selected cells during the range selection. In addition to that, I cannot find any information about that option in the given doc. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-range-selection/.

Is there any possibility to deselect cells with ctrl and another key or do I have to create a feature request, so that they may implement that?

Just as further information, we use the api.getRangeSelections() to process and visualize the given values in a custom status bar component. We expect that customers demand to exclude unexpected data instead of deselecting everything and restart from scratch.

Thank you in advance for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

Very good question. After a quick research on the doc, I can recommend you to enable advance range selection, and prompt users that they can exclude their selection only if they go around the cells they want not to select.
For example:

[image]

Here above, I selected cells with 'advance range select' ( `CTRL + selection` ) and remained a cell none-selected. Before I start to select with range, I figure it out which one I am not going to select, so it becomes easier to manage cells to be none-selected.

Go and experience yourself with this link: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/range-selection/#example-range-selection-advanced